# cURL timeout on heroku

Tags: php, symfony, curl, heroku

I'm using a Symfony2 app on heroku and I can't connect to my API.

I explain you the scenario :

1. I connect me in my app through a form
2. When I'm correctly log in my app, an event listener is triggered
3. I access the URL which delivers me the API token and I save those credentials in the user session
4. I redirect the connected (to the app and to the API) user to the homepage of the app

So my problem is at the point 3. I tried with cURL and a file_get_contents to access the URL and both aren't worked.

When I try to access the URL which delivers me the OAuth token necessary to access my API, it fails. I tried to access this URL manually in the browser (or Postman) and it returns well the OAuth token.

The event listener :

```
        // Call of the url to deliver the token
        $clientAPI = $this->em->getRepository('BgAPIBundle:Client')->findOneBy(array('providerAccess' => 'pcv'));
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, urldecode($this->router->generate('fos_oauth_server_token', array('grant_type' => 'http://www.myapp/api/grants/api_key', 'client_id' => $clientAPI->getId() . '_' . $clientAPI->getRandomId(), 'client_secret' => $clientAPI->getSecret(), 'api_key' => $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser()->getApiKey()), true)));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $this->error = $response; // Only if there is problem
        curl_close($curl);

        // Write in logs
        $date = new \DateTime('now');
        if (preg_match('#error#', $this->error)) {
            $this->logger->error('Error on authentication success to deliver the OAuth token for ' . $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser() . ' the ' . $date->format('j/m/Y - H:i:s') . ' with message : ' . $this->error);
        }
```

The error from Heroku and my logs :

```
heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/token?grant_type=http://www.app/api/grants/api_key&client_id=261_1ws6mvgmbeisgcsw4wokwk8k400og88gs0csssg0gk0884080s&client_secret=1ghmf01c1a4kc448ssgwg8sw04840c4ww8k00gg4o0k8w04g4&api_key=7f5284ac5ec8b35527d3c16dafa52a89" host=app-max.herokuapp.com request_id=dc8960fd-d154-4e5d-bc2f-34d4f25b8070 fwd="46.51.146.244" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30006ms status=503 bytes=0 
app.ERROR: Une erreur est survenue lors de l'attribution du token OAuth de maxime@tetst.fr le 25/11/2015 - 16:12:40 avec le message : <!DOCTYPE html>     <html>     <head>       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">       <style type="text/css">         html, body, iframe { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }         iframe { display: block; width: 100%; border: none; }       </style>     <title>Application Error</title>     </head>     <body>       <iframe src="//s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html">         <p>Application Error</p>       </iframe>     </body>     </html> [] []
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you try to set `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`? E.g:` curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but yes I tried and it doesn't work

Comment: and what about `USERAGENT`? `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2225.0 Safari/537.36');`

Comment: Unfortunately, same result

Comment: @MaximePicard pls show us the code for `$this->router->generate()`.

Comment: @SabujHassan this method is from Symfony2 to generate an URL : http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.html#method_generate

Comment: Did you try on local? I mean in localhost? is it working before? its hard to test in heroku. I suggest test by repl, test step by step, you can use phpStorm

Comment: Yes it works well on localhost (dev/prod environment) and on Scalingo/PlatformSH (two other services as Heroku)

Comment: are we sure that the correct url is being generated?  also can we check to see if the API is being accessed at all and just isn't able to respond for some reason (maybe some logging at the start of the API method).

Comment: I post the solution for my question. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution :

EventListener

```
$tokenController = new FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Controller\TokenController($this->oauth2); //  $this->oauth2 is the @fos_oauth_server.server service
$credentials = $tokenController->tokenAction($request);
$response = $credentials->getContent();
```

This is just another solution to log in my API, whithout using cURL and the URL that give the token.